# How Iterator implement in TreeSet

Tags: iterator, treeset

I read java source about TreeSet , but I can not find the implement of Iterator in TreeSet. Could anybody tell me how Iterator implements in TreeSet, and where is the source code in TreeSet? thanks!

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you look at the source code of [`TreeSet<E>.iterator()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet.iterator%28%29) you see:

```java
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return m.navigableKeySet().iterator();
}
```

Next search for the definition of [`m`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet.0m):

```java
private transient NavigableMap<E,Object> m;
```

So obviously `TreeSet` points to a `NavigableMap` which is not really a surprise because [`TreeSet`'s JavaDoc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeSet.java#27) says:

> A `NavigableSet` implementation based on a `TreeMap`.

Okay, so let us check the source code of `TreeMap`. There you will find the method [`navigableKeySet()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.navigableKeySet%28%29) which was referenced above, pointing to a member named [`navigableKeySet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.0navigableKeySet) which is of type [`TreeMap.KeySet<K>`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.KeySet), a static inner class. There in turn you will find an [`iterator()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.KeySet.iterator%28%29) method and so forth. The `TreeMap` class contains quite a lot of inner classes, the whole structure is pretty complex, but if you are interested you can sort it out by yourself. I think I gave you a good headstart. `;-)`

Comment: This does not really answer the question how it is implemented. It just points to many links -- which are useful -- but reading it up there takes much more time than a concise answer on SO..

Comment: Thanks for digging up this 6 years old question just so as to complain about it. I disagree with your criticism, though. I was both explaining and pointing to the source code because the OP asked for details about the internal implementation. In order to make this order concise, as you demand(!), I am not quoting or paraphrasing everything. This sense of entitlement - I have to explain everything so you don't have to click links and look for more details if you need them - is either sad or funny, hard to decide. Sorry you do not like the answer, the OP thanked me for it, I wrote it for him.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kriegaex
i was able to dig up and find the base class for TreeMap Iterators
in TreeMap.java Line# 1466

As we can see from the source - Iterator is implemented via the predecessor and successor methods that accept a child node parameter.

Start from the min value, than for each next() find its in-order successor.

```
 abstract class PrivateEntryIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    Entry<K,V> next;
    Entry<K,V> lastReturned;
    int expectedModCount;

    PrivateEntryIterator(Entry<K,V> first) {
        expectedModCount = modCount;
        lastReturned = null;
        next = first;
    }

    public final boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    final Entry<K,V> nextEntry() {
        Entry<K,V> e = next;
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        next = successor(e);
        lastReturned = e;
        return e;
    }

    final Entry<K,V> prevEntry() {
        Entry<K,V> e = next;
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        next = predecessor(e);
        lastReturned = e;
        return e;
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (lastReturned == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        // deleted entries are replaced by their successors
        if (lastReturned.left != null && lastReturned.right != null)
            next = lastReturned;
        deleteEntry(lastReturned);
        expectedModCount = modCount;
        lastReturned = null;
    }
}
```

The successor method traverses the tree:

```
static <K,V> TreeMap.Entry<K,V> successor(Entry<K,V> t) {
        if (t == null)
            return null;
        else if (t.right != null) {
            Entry<K,V> p = t.right;
            while (p.left != null)
                p = p.left;
            return p;
        } else {
            Entry<K,V> p = t.parent;
            Entry<K,V> ch = t;
            while (p != null && ch == p.right) {
                ch = p;
                p = p.parent;
            }
            return p;
        }
}
```

Thanks @kriegaex for the guidance.